# Reading sertain set of key-value pair in JSON using python

Tags: json, python-3.x

suppose I have below json data, my requirement is I only want to parse few key-value pair to be print. Like I want name,description,start & end key-value pair will be printed just by calling print once. All other key-value pair should be skipped while printing. Only the asked above information is needed for my work, so I don't want to keep all other key_value pair.

```
'events': [
    {
      'name': {
        'text': 'Sample Event',
        'html': 'Sample Event'
      },
      'description': {
        'text': 'This is a test event',
        'html': '<P>This is a test event</P>'
      },
      'start': {
        'timezone': 'Asia/Kolkata',
        'local': '2018-10-12T19:00:00',
        'utc': '2018-10-12T13:30:00Z'
      },
      'end': {
        'timezone': 'Asia/Kolkata',
        'local': '2018-10-12T22:00:00',
        'utc': '2018-10-12T16:30:00Z'
      },
      'organization_id': '269994560152',
      'created': '2018-09-02T15:48:49Z',
      'changed': '2018-09-02T15:49:00Z',
      'capacity': 1,
      'capacity_is_custom': False,
      'status': 'live',
      'currency': 'USD',
      'listed': True,
      'shareable': True,
      'invite_only': False,
      'online_event': False,
      'show_remaining': True,
      'tx_time_limit': 480,
      'hide_start_date': False,
      'hide_end_date': False,
      'locale': 'en_US',
      'is_locked': False,
      'privacy_setting': 'unlocked',
      'is_series': False,
      'is_series_parent': False,
      'is_reserved_seating': False,
      'show_pick_a_seat': False,
      'show_seatmap_thumbnail': False,
      'show_colors_in_seatmap_thumbnail': False,
      'source': 'create_2.0',
      'is_free': True,
      'version': '3.0.0',
      'logo_id': None,
      'category_id': '199',
      'subcategory_id': None,
      'format_id': '16',
      'logo': None
    }
```